# Adding a relative date range facet to a Search API view using the "last updated" field

Tags: search, datetime, 9

I would like to add a facet to a search_api view filtering on the content "changed" field. I would like to use friendly naming like "This week", "This month" etc.
There is an [answer here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/41781/apachesolr-search-results-facet-filter-by-date-range) stating that custom code is needed. However this answer is for Drupal 6 (about 8 years old) and refers to a date range  field while "changed" is a timestamp.

Currently if I add Date processor capability to this facet I have a granularity option. If I select a month granularity I get a basic "time ago" feature but seem to get very odd results.

EG. Clicking on "3 months ago (3)" in the below list gives me 13 items.
The url generated is `&facets_query=&keyword[0]=last_updated:2021-05-22` (As of today July 22)

```
Last updated
3 months ago (3)
6 months ago (3)
7 months ago (2)
8 months ago (9)
10 months ago (1)
11 months ago (6)
1 year 0 months ago (7)
```

Questions:

1. Is there an updated answer available for creating a friendly set of date ranges?
2. Why could I be I getting these incorrect facet counts?